# When cloning and fetching from Unfuddle, I only get the master, how can I get the branches?

Tags: git, unfuddle

I follow the instructions on unfuddle exactly and no matter what I only can the master back.  Pushing branches works fine, but not fetching.

Does anyone have any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `git checkout -t origin/branch` after fetch?

Comment: thank you very much.  That worked!  Do you happen to know why this branch does not show when I do a 'git branch'?

Comment: You're welcome; I've added it as an answer so that you can accept it. the branch wasn't showing because `git branch` lists only local branches. To list also remote ones use `git branch -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you list branches you can do one of 3 things:

```
git branch
```

will show the local branches (only one will be created after a clone)

```
git branch -r
```

will show you the remote tracking branches. This is what you were interested in.

```
git branch -a
```

will show you all the branches (local and remote tracking)

To get a remote tracking branch to be tracked by a local branch,

```
git checkout -t origin/branchname
```

You may not need to do this if, for example, you just want to merge a remote branch to your current one.

```
git merge origin/somebranch
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch a remote, the branches are in your repository, but as remote branches. `git branch` lists only *local* branches, so it doesn't appear.

You must make the branch local with `git checkout -t origin/mybranch` (this will also check it out in your working copy), or `git branch mybranch origin/mybranch` to create it without checkout.